# Rational canonical form of a matrix $M \in GL(n,\mathbb{F}_2)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, minimal-polynomials

I've got a problem with understanding the following citation from [XOR-counts and lightweight multiplication with fixed elements in binary finite fields](https://rdcu.be/bRjca) on page 10 in the beginning.

> Recall that a matrix $M \in GL(n,\mathbb{F}_2)$ is similar to its (unique) rational canonical form. If $M$ has an irreducible minimal polynomial $m$
>   with $deg(m) = k$ then there exists a $d ≥ 1$ so that $kd = n$ and the rational canonical form is $\bigoplus ^d _{i=1} C_m$ where $C_m$ is a companion matrix for the minimal polynomial and $\bigoplus$ denotes block diagonal matrix.

But that would mean that the degree of the minimal polynomial would be a divisor of $n$. But that's not always the case. I found a counterexample on Wikipedia in [Frobenius normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form#Example) where $ n=8$ and $deg(m) = 6$, so no such $k \in \mathbb{N}$ exists.
Does that mean that the property mentioned in the article is caused by the fact that we consider a regular matrix or a fact that we consider a matrix over $\mathbb{F}_2$? Thank you.

Comment: Is the minimal polynomial in your example irreducible?

Comment: @BrianMoehring According to Wolfram Alpha, it isn't. So if the minimal polynomial is irreducible then its degree is a divisor of $n$? I assumed that minimal polynomial must be always irreducible as in finite fields. Which properties of a matrix change when the minimal polynomial is irreducible? Thank you

Comment: To your first question, yes.  It's known that the minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial [Cayley-Hamilton], and that if an irreducible divides the characteristic polynomial, it also divides the minimal polynomial.   Together, this means that when the minimal polynomial $m(x)$ is irreducible, then the characteristic polynomial equals $(m(x))^k$ for some positive integer $k.$  To your second question, aside from properties of e.g. the rational canonical form being as described in your original question, I don't know any basic properties of such matrices.

Comment: @BrianMoehring thank you, that is a very elegant proof

Comment: Now that I'm a little more awake, it occurs to me that the full power of Cayley-Hamilton is unnecessary for the above conclusion.  The second proposition I mentioned suffices.  My conclusions stay the same.